# Travis CI only executing single test file phpunit

Tags: php, testing, continuous-integration, phpunit, travis-ci

I'm having a bit of a problem with Travis CI and PHPUnit - it seems to be only executing a single test file - strangely - the tests/unit/helpers/XMLFileTest.php.

https://travis-ci.org/Matt-Barber/DataCruncher/jobs/151193473

Here is a copy of the phpunit.xml.dist I'm using :

```
<phpunit
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
strict="true"
bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
verbose = "true"
>
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="unit">
        <directory suffix='.php'>./tests/unit</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="integration">
        <directory suffix='.php'>./tests/integration</directory>    
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="functional">
        <directory suffix='.php'>./tests/functional</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
<logging>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="build/coverage" title="CSV_Cruncher" charset="UTF-8" yui="true" highlight="true" lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
    <log type="coverage-clover" target="build/logs/clover.xml"/>
</logging>
<filter>
    <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">./src</directory>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
</phpunit>
```

And the travis.yml I'm using

```
language: php
php:
    - '5.6'
    - '7.0'

before_script:
    - composer install
    - find . -type f -name *.csv -exec chmod 777 {} +
    - mkdir build

script: 
    - phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml.dist --debug

after_script: 
    - php vendor/bin/coveralls -v
```

My folder structure for my src is :

```
src
    - Analysis
        - Statistics.php
    - Config
        - Validation.php
    - Exceptions
        - [various]
    - Helpers
        - DataInterface.php
        - DataFile.php
        - CSVFile.php
        - XMLFile.php
    - Segmentation 
        - Merger.php
        - Query.php
        - Split.php
```

Tests is the same:

```
tests
    - unit
        - Analysis
            - StatisticsTest.php
```

and so on....

Here is a link to the git repo
https://github.com/Matt-Barber/DataCruncher/tree/develop

Any reason as to why the rest of the tests aren't executing? They seem fine running both on local and through a vagrant machine with XDebug...It's hurting my brain (as you can see from the commit history)

Any questions, and help muchly appreciated!

Cheers!

### Updated

The answer is to remember

```
mv Folder folder
```

isn't the same as

```
git mv Folder folder
```

thanks hcr! for pointing out the difference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple problem of case-sensitivity. You've specified your test directory as `./tests/..` in your `phpunit.xml.dist` and your repo has the following structure:

```
Tests/[...]
tests/unit/Helpers/XMLFileTest.php
```

PhpUnit will only find the second one on Travis. Just make sure that the use the same case everywhere.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that... thanks! mv and git mv doh!

Comment: I definitely know these issues from my own experience ;)